# Creating python packages in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've created two projects in visual studios. I want to share code between them. I don't want to directly add this code to either of these projects.

If this was a C# project, I'd go and create a class libary. The python equivilent is to use a package. Apparently you just create a folder hierachy and add the special `__init__.py` at the top to expose it as a package, [I've been reading this](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages). Each file is then a module, and the folder structure is used in a similar way as namespaces within the class libary would be used in C#.

**However, there is no package project in VS2015**. Adding all my code as solution items doesn't seem right, and solution level folders aren't real directories anyway (so it wouldn't work). **How do I organise my standalone python packages in Visual Studios?**

For reference, here is what my project looks like. Now what? Where can I start creating my shared packages?

[image]

Comment: I'm looking how to do this too and I am surprised it is not already answered. I can hardly find any relevant results googling. Perhaps RStudio and devtools have spoiled me.

Comment: Okay I just found that there is the template Add > New Item > Python Package which will add a folder with an __init__.py folder to the solution.